# Google map not displaying in google map api v2

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2, google-maps-api-2

Hi i am trying to run a map application using the code provided by google but the map not displaying,it displayed for yesterday now a blank screen is showing on my device

When i run the program the following is the log

**LogCat**

```
01-02 11:33:36.203: D/dalvikvm(20623): GC_CONCURRENT freed 188K, 10% free 7589K/8391K, paused 17ms+10ms, total 86ms
01-02 11:33:36.203: D/dalvikvm(20623): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 43ms
01-02 11:33:36.789: D/dalvikvm(20623): GC_CONCURRENT freed 343K, 11% free 7817K/8775K, paused 12ms+2ms, total 68ms
01-02 11:33:36.789: D/dalvikvm(20623): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 31ms
01-02 11:33:36.789: D/dalvikvm(20623): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 31ms
01-02 11:33:36.789: D/dalvikvm(20623): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 31ms
01-02 11:33:36.789: D/dalvikvm(20623): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 32ms
01-02 11:33:36.789: D/dalvikvm(20623): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 33ms
01-02 11:33:36.796: D/dalvikvm(20623): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 36ms
01-02 11:33:36.937: D/AbsListView(20623): Get MotionRecognitionManager
01-02 11:33:37.007: D/dalvikvm(20623): GC_CONCURRENT freed 255K, 11% free 8050K/8967K, paused 17ms+3ms, total 59ms
01-02 11:33:37.039: E/GooglePlayServicesUtil(20623): The Google Play services resources were not found. Check your project configuration to ensure that the resources are included.
01-02 11:33:37.109: D/libEGL(20623): loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libEGL_POWERVR_SGX540_120.so
01-02 11:33:37.125: D/libEGL(20623): loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_POWERVR_SGX540_120.so
01-02 11:33:37.132: D/libEGL(20623): loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv2_POWERVR_SGX540_120.so
01-02 11:33:37.242: D/OpenGLRenderer(20623): Enabling debug mode 0
01-02 11:33:37.492: D/dalvikvm(20623): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 267K, 11% free 8188K/9159K, paused 35ms, total 35ms
01-02 11:33:37.539: D/dalvikvm(20623): GC_CONCURRENT freed 327K, 12% free 8318K/9351K, paused 3ms+2ms, total 32ms
01-02 11:33:37.539: D/dalvikvm(20623): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 20ms
01-02 11:33:37.570: D/dalvikvm(20623): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 453K, 13% free 8191K/9351K, paused 21ms, total 21ms
01-02 11:33:37.679: D/dalvikvm(20623): GC_CONCURRENT freed 304K, 11% free 8335K/9351K, paused 17ms+40ms, total 105ms
```

It is showing google play service not installed.But i installed the play service and imported it to my eclipse workspace and the i added it to my project using

> **project-properties-android**

This is my manifest file

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.googlemap"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="14"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true"/>
     <permission
    android:name="com.googlemap.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature"/>

      <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
       <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
       <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
      <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
      <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
      <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
      <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />    
       <uses-permission android:name="com.googlemap.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />




    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
                 <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />

        <activity
            android:name="com.googlemap.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>


        </activity>
         <meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
    android:value="My api key"/>

         <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" 
             android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

    </application>

</manifest>
```

**xml file**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:id="@+id/map"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"/>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.googlemap;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {
    GoogleMap map;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        if (map == null) {
         map = ((SupportMapFragment)  getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
                   .getMap();
         LatLng loc = new LatLng(8.557845, 76.880727);

            map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

            map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(loc, 13));

            map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                    .title("Google map")
                    .snippet(" IT city .")
                    .position(loc));
        }
    }

}
```

**project.properties file**

```
target=Google Inc.:Google APIs:17
android.library=false
android.library.reference.1=../google-play-services_lib
```

Please help me.i have tried some solution but i am not getting the result
Thanks in advance..

Comment: What have you changed from yesterday. Please cross verify all changes you have made. And try to check - Please cross verify package name both in API console and in manifest file. - Please cross verify API key in both API console and in manifest file.

Answer (score 2):

```
The Google Play services resources were not found. Check your project configuration to ensure that the resources are included.
```

Looks like you have not setup google play services properly.

Follow the steps in the below link and setup google play services.

http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html

You also need to check the availability of google play services. Check the topic **Check for Google Play Services** in the below link.

http://developer.android.com/training/location/receive-location-updates.html

Your min sdk is 14

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="14"
```

So you need to use `MapFragment` instead of `SupportMapFrament`.

Change to

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:id="@+id/map"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"/>
```

Replace

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {
```

By

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
```

Change

```
map = ((SupportMapFragment)  getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
               .getMap();
```

to

```
map = ((MapFragment)  getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
               .getMap();
```

Comment: Are you sure that it is true? "So you need to use MapFragment instead of SupportMapFrament."

Comment: @CássioOliveira yes i am sure want me  to post the link to the docs?

Comment: @CássioOliveira https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/MapFragment. check the line just before the topic develoepers guide

Comment: thanks all...actually the problem is with the google play service installed in my device.once i updated the play service the map is showing in the application..

Answer (score 1):

See here,just change the api key with your key in manifest file and follow these steps:
and **make sure that generate api key with package name which is mentioned in android manifest file and your google_play_services_lib project should be present in your project's work space only.**

Manifest file:

```
    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.geeklabs.map.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
    android:value="replace with your API key"/>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

MainActivity.java:

```
    package com.geeklabs.map;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

}
```

activity_main.xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:id="@+id/map"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"/>
```

After got this let me know.

Comment: thanks all...actually the problem is with the google play service installed in my device.once i updated the play service the map is showing in the application..

Comment: well come keep it up.. :)